# Mongoose.js - array of geospatial locations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would need to have something like this

```
{
    event : "something",
    location : [
        {
            long:25, lat:34
        }.
        }
            long:25, lat:35
        }.
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Is this possible? And is it possible to have a geospatial index for the location field? I would have queries with $nearSphere.

Thanks

EDIT: mongoose schema question

having the schema entry be something like location : [{ lon : Number, lat: Number}] gets me to end up with an aditional _id for each object in the location array. Is that 1. a problem? 2. a nuissance? 3. something that i can fix?

ex :
    {
    "lon":1,
    "lat":2,
    "_id":"50bfeea2a3092d1d67000007"
    },

Comment: I would use `,` instead of `.` between the `location` array elements :). but seriously, why wouldn't work, have you tried? Check [Geospatial Indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) in the manual, it sounds me exactly what you want.

Comment: I've been reading it three times already and just now I saw the damn Spherical true part for geoNear. You can answer the question if you want to so I can accept it for future reference.

Comment: Actually I should amend the question with an actual problem in Mongoose. Please check edit.

Comment: I see @JohnnyHK already answered your edited question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want each of the `location` elements to have an `_id` field, you can disable that by explicitly defining a schema for the elements with the [`_id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) option set to `false`.

Like this:

```
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    event: String,
    location: [new Schema({long: Number, lat: Number}, {_id: false})]
});
```

Comment: Ok great thank you. But... should I ? Or shouldn't I? I dont think that I will ever search by those ids though.

Comment: @InnocentPixel If you're not going to access the elements by id and you have a lot of elements I'd disable it as they're at least 12 bytes each.